# How do I sign out of a Twitter account on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

When I use an app such as Safari, I can choose to "Tweet" a page and it uses my Twitter account. How do I sign out of that Twitter account so that if I give my device to someone else, they can no longer tweet things on my behalf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Feb 27, 2023, both the original answer and even [the Twitter's existing documentation](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/revoke-twitter-access-on-ios-app) are not accurate.

For the following configuration:

- Twitter: version 9.45
- iOS: version 16.0

To log out:

1. Tap on your profile icon in the upper left of the screen to open the profile menu
2. In this menu, tap the Add Account icon (upper right of menu) to open the Accounts sub-menu. In this menu, you should see your account, and the options to `Create a new account` or `Add an existing account`.
3. Swipe left on your account to reveal the option to Log out

---

**Original Answer**

The only way to sign out of an account is to actually delete it, according to the UI. This is tied into the Twitter integration that was part of iOS 5.

To sign out of the account, you need to:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Choose **Twitter**
3. Tap on the account you want to sign out of.
4. Tap **Delete Account**

This does not delete your actual Twitter account, it just logs you out and removes that accounts credentials from your device.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was getting CRAZY because I wasn't trying to delete my acount, just to do the logout on my Iphone, but nobody told me that in any website. Thank's!!!!

Comment: Answer is old and needs to be updated. There is no account section in Settings-> Twitter